# Can I play a video on a WebView inside the app itself rather than opening a browser window?

Tags: android

I have a livestream from my Raspberry Pi and I am able to view it on my Android app normally using a WebView. However, it opens a new browser window. Is there any way it can play within the app window itself, rather than in a browser window?

Comment: Do you mean that clicking a link in your `WebView` to that video opens the separate browser?

Comment: No, I don't click any link. I created the ```WebView``` in the ```onCreate()``` method itself, so it plays in the separate browser as soon as I open the app. 
Also, I have only tested this on the Emulator, could this be an issue related only to Emulators?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. It's likely due to `WebView`'s default behavior. Are you setting a `WebViewClient` on it? If not, try setting a default one on it: `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`.